# PowerBI API - How to update the credentials for a datasource PER dataset

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I am trying to update the credentials used by a PowerBI dataset when connecting to its data source using the Power BI API.
However, what is achievable via the PowerBI service UI doesnt seem possible via the API.

I have a number of PowerBI reports with a number of discreet datasets that share a common datasource.
I am trying to change the credentials used by a dataset when connecting to the data source without changing the credentials for ALL datasets.

For example I can change the credentials for a data set in the UI here:

[image]

In the API the only request I can find that allows me to update the datasource credentials is

```
pbiAdminClient.Gateways.UpdateDatasourceAsync
```

Which takes a request object of

```
UpdateDatasourceRequest
```

that allows you to specify the SQL username/password. However this changes the credentials for the entire datasource (and thus all datasets using it).
I need to be able to specify the group, dataset, datasource and credentials but cant find an appropriate request in the API.

I have seen use of the REST endpoint direct

```
$"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupId}/datasets/{datasetKey}/updatedatasources"
```

but that doesnt allow credentials to be provided but DOES allow you to specify the group, dataset and some datasource details.

Is what I am trying to do even possible? The fact that I can do this via the UI makes me want to believe it is.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an On-Prem or VNet Gateway you can create [multiple connections per Data Source](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/multiple-data-source-definitions-on-the-on-premises-data-gateway-for-the-same-data-source/), each with its own credentials.

For cloud data sources there's only connection per user, so to change the credentials for only one Dataset, take over the Dataset with a different user and have that user set the credentials.